# Getting a chronological list of frontmost windows in Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm looking for a way to get a list that contains the title of the frontmost window and the time it became the frontmost window in OSX. I guess applescript won't be able to listen for the event that a different window became the frontmost window. How could I tackle this problem?

Comment: Across all applications?

Comment: Yes, do you think that is doable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of opened windows cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134605/get-a-list-of-opened-windows-cocoa).  See Peter Hosey's answer,

Comment: At best, this would be a hack on top of the Accessibility APIs.